# sql server image data - null value using sqlsrv_query of php

Tags: php, image, sql-server-2008

I a fetching image data stored in the db - something like 0X92384902340923904823..... Make a call from php using sqlsrv_query.

It always returns me null though there is data in the database for these images.

```
$sql = "SELECT ProdImage FROM Product WHERE ProdId=".addslashes($prod_id)
                $params = array();
                $options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );
                $result = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql , $params, $options );

                if($result != NULL && sqlsrv_num_rows($result) > 0)
                {
                    $obj = sqlsrv_fetch_object($result);
                    return ($obj->ProdImage);
                }
```

Comment: You will need to post some code. This is unanswerable.

Comment: i have edited my question. please have a look

Answer (score 0):

[`sqlsrv_query()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296184%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) supports prepared statements with `?` placeholders.  You are concatenating in `$prod_id`, but you have not quoted it properly in single quotes as a string -- and that is a syntax error in the SQL.  Instead, use a placeholder `?`.

```
 $sql = "SELECT ProdImage FROM Product WHERE ProdId = ?";
 // pass $prod_id as a parameter.
 $params = array($prod_id);
 $options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );
 $result = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql , $params, $options );
```

Using your plain query method, which is *not recommended*, you would need to quote `$prod_id` in single quotes. Don't do this if `$prod_id` comes from any sort of user input.

```
 $sql = "SELECT ProdImage FROM Product WHERE ProdId = '$prod_id'";
```

Comment: Query works fine for me and product id is not a varchar its int.. so need not put it in single quotes.
The data is in byte array hence it is giving me null value so i am not very sure how to fetch it.